# Want to update the entered entry in databse. I have code and showing error:

Tags: mysql

This is the code where i have to update the entry in database by using form edit update:

```html
<?php

$nm=$_POST['name'];
$ag=$_POST["age"];
$em=$_POST['email'];
$cn=$_POST['contact'];
$ad=$_POST['address'];

require("connection.php");
$sql = "update signup set name='$nm', age='$ag', email='$em', contact='$cn', address='$ad' WHERE id='$id'";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
    echo "Updated";
} else 
{
    echo "Error:";
}
?>
```

These are the errors showing.. and i have tried isset then also showing same error for assigned variable.

```css
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\update.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\update.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\update.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: contact in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\update.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\update.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Signup\update.php on line 10
Updated
```

Comment: The error messages are pretty self-explanatory. Your post data doesn't have any of the parameters mentioned. Check the form that is submitting to this script to see what field names it is sending, and that it is using POST instead of GET. RE line 10, you haven't defined the variable $id. Lastly, your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Assigned all the variables including "id" by using "isset" with "if" and code runs but still data not updated

Comment: Are you getting any errors with the changes? If not, echo the $sql variable and see if it executes in phpAdmin (or similar). Edit your question and show the results of echoing $sql and any error messages you get with the new code. Also show the new code.

Comment: update signup set name='New Ashok nagar', age='', email='', contact='', address='' where id=''

Comment: this result i got when i have used echo of the variable $sql.

Comment: Please find the new code below post.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $nm=$_POST['name'];
}
if(isset($_POST["age"])){
    $ag=$_POST["age"];
}
if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    $em=$_POST['email'];
}
if(isset($_POST["contact"])){
    $cn=$_POST['contact'];
}
if(isset($_POST["address"])){
    $ad=$_POST['address'];
}
    require("connection.php");
    $sql = "update 'signup' set 'name'='{$nm}', age='$ag', 'email'='{$em}', 'contact'='{$cn}', 'address'='{$ad}' WHERE 'signup'.'id'='{$id}'";
    if($conn->query($sql)==="TRUE")
    {
        echo "Updated";
    } 
else 
    {
       echo "Error:";
    }
    ?>
```

Hope this answers your question. If it does, please rate my answer

Comment: Didn't get the result. I have already used your format as well.

Comment: $sql = "update 'signup' set 'name'='{$nm}', age='$ag', 'email'='{$em}', 'contact'='{$cn}', 'address'='{$ad}' WHERE 'signup'.'id'='{$id}'";                        
Try putting single-inverted commas around signup, name, etc like above    
Also make the UPDATE and SET keywords to caps    
Show the output of your page also.

Comment: Use this to find your error:                                                                         if($conn->query($sql)==="TRUE")
    {
        echo "Updated";
    } 
else 
    {
       echo "Error:".$conn->error;
    }